# How do I sort variables into other variables by ranking in python

Tags: python, sorting

So I am trying to make a program to imrove my python skills which is basically a lucky wheel, you get several items which are all ranked by numbers, I have made the items randomly generate but how would i make them print in order? I assume that the sort() method won't be any use in this situation.

```
# to sort: itemrating1, itemrating2, itemrating3
print(toprateditem)
print(meditem)
print(lowitem)
```

that is basically what I want to do, I hope I explained it well.

Comment: Compare the values manually to order them? Use `min()` and `max()` ? This seems like a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

You can store them in a list:

```
allitems = [item1, item2, item3]
```

You can call `sort()` on the list or just return `max(allitems)` and `min(allitems)`